# Eclipse Neon icon size in Ubuntu 16.04 hidpi

Tags: 16.04, eclipse

I have read that Eclipse Neon has now support for hidpi but icons are extremely small when using a hidpi notebook in Ubuntu 16.04.

Is there any command line argument or environment variable that I have to set so it works?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At least in my case (ASUS UX303UB, Eclipse Neon 4.6.0RC1, Ubuntu 16.04), it was possible to get proper icons by adding:

```
-Dswt.autoScale=175
```

at the end of `$ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse.ini`

Comment: This indeed helped (with neon.3), but when I needed the scale back at 100% changing the mentioned parameter to 100 didn't help. Nor did adding `-Dswt.enable.autoScale=false`. Any suggestions?

Comment: OK, I figured it out. It was the automatically created `~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop` after I pinned the running upscaled eclipse to the Unity launcher. It contained all the `eclipse.ini` parameters in the `Exec=` action. Changing this just to `eclipse` or running eclipse from the command line normally worked.

Answer (score 2):

For me the following worked:

```
GDK_DPI_SCALE=0.5 GDK_SCALE=2 eclipse
```

Setting GDK_SCALE to 2 alone fixed the icon size but made all text huge. I had to set GDK_DPI_SCALE to 0.5 to counter the effect on the font size.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a launcher, use the following in the command editor (adapted from Zoltan):

```
env GDK_DPI_SCALE=0.4 env GDK_SCALE=2 eclipse
```

I'm using it on a 4k 15.6' display.

Answer (score 0):

```
-Dswt.autoScale=exact
```

worked for me. It apparently used my Gnome Tweak Tool font scaling setting of **1.35** The **autoScale** options are explained at [Tweaking SWT's auto-scaling](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/platform.php#swt-autoscale-tweaks)